# How can I remove some content from RWD default home page

Tags: rwd-theme, parent-child-theme, home-page

I have chosen to develop a child thee based on RWD parent theme. How can I remove some garbage that I actually don't need. I marked the piece of html that I want to remove, in the attached screenshot. It is not in any block, as I can see in my template hints (see attached image)
[image: company about us contact us etc.....]

I want that COMPANY, ABOUT US, CONTACT US, CUSTOMER SERVICE, PRIVACY POLICY links removed so that I can isnert something more useful in their place. How can I do that?

Comment: check you home page from admin you can find it from there.

Comment: This content is actually NOT on the Home CMS page in admin. So, I don't know where does it come from, except from 3column template. But, still, there is no marking that it is in a block.

Comment: check home page layout xml code if any.

Comment: I think it will come from static block and static block call either in cma page or in any layout xml file. need to check all static block if any then disable that static block.

Comment: @SHPatel Thanks so much! I found it in cms.xml and removed it. Can you please make an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it from below suggestion.

1. You can find it from home page from admin. check home page content or layout xml.

If not there then you have to check it in home page layout xml.

2. You can find it from `cms.xml` which is located in your theme or parent theme (RWD Theme).

Check `cms.xml` code from your side. You will be find out relevant code from here.